# Github API Conditional Requests with paging

Tags: api, caching, github, paging, etag

Context: let's say we want to retrieve whole list of Starred repositories by given User periodically (ones per day, hour or few minutes).

There are at least 2 approaches to do that:

1. execute GET to https://api.github.com/users/evereq/starred and use Url with rel='next' in 'Link' Response Headers to get next page Url (we should do that till we get no "next" page in response, mean that we reach the end). Seems that is recommended approach (by Github).
2. iterating 'page' parameter (from 1 to infinite) using GET to https://api.github.com/users/evereq/starred?page=XXX till you get 0 results in response. Ones you get 0 results, you finish (not recommended because for example instead of page numbers Github can move to "hash" values. Github already did it for some API operations.).

Now, let's say we want to make sure we use Conditional Requests (see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#conditional-requests) to save our API usage limits (and traffic, trees in the world, etc.).

So we add for example 'If-None-Match' to our Requests Headers and check if response Status is 304 (Not Modified). If so, it means that nothing was changed from our last request. That works OK.

The issue however that what we have in 1) and 2) above, related to the way how we detect when to stop is NOT working anymore when you use Conditional Requests!

I.e. with approach 1), you don't get Link Response Headers at all when you use Conditional Requests.
So you will need to execute one more request with page bigger than page for which you already have ETag and see that it return 0 results and than you know you are done. That way you basically "waste" one request to Github API (because it miss Conditional Requests Headers).

Same with approach 2), you basically have 0 responses in every request with status 304...  So again, to know you are done, you need to make at least one additional request which do return 0 results.

So the question is: when we do conditional requests with the fact that Github API does not send back Link Response Header (at least with queries using ETag which result Status 304) how could we know when to stop paging? Is it a bug in Github API implementation OR I miss something?

We don't know maximum page number, so to get when to stop we should execute one more "waste" request and check if we get 0 results back!

I also can't found how to query Github for total count of starred repositories (so I can calculate how many pages I should iterate in advice), same as responses does not include something like "X-Total-Count" so I know when to stop using simple math for pages count.

Any ideas how to save that one ('end') request and still use Conditional Requests?

If you do one request per day, it's OK to accept such waste, but what if you do such request ones per minute? You will quickly use all your API usage Limits!

UPDATE

Well, after a few more tests, I see now following "rule" (can't however found it anywhere in the docs, so note sure if its rule or just assumption): if user star something new, result for EVERY requested page contains different ETag value compared to previous and does not have status 304 anymore! That means that it's enough to just request first page and check for status. if its 304 (not modified), we do NOT need to check next pages, ie we are DONE as nothing was changed in any page. Is it correct approach or just coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

We indeed return pagination relations in the `Link` response header when the content has changed [1](https://gist.github.com/pengwynn/6366324). Since we don't support a `since` parameter for that call, you'll need to sort by most recent results and maintain a client-side cursor for the last known ID or timestamp (based on your sort criteria) and stop paging when it shows up in your paginated results. Conditional requests will just let you know if Page 1 has changed.

We haven't settled on a way to return counts on our listing methods, but a really low-tech solution is to set the page size to 1, grab the `rel=last` Link relation and check its `page` parameter value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, doing page size = 1, we can save some trees in the world (i.e. traffic), but we still waste our Github API usage limits because it just don't work for Conditional requests at all :( Anyway, thanks for an idea to minimize our (and Github) traffic :D So question is still open: why Github can't return Links headers even if it was Conditional Request? I.e. it's irrelevant if content was changed or not if you only need to know if next page exists and should be processed or we finish, right? Are the any technical limits that prevent to ALWAYS return LINK in response headers (even for 304)?

Comment: I.e. see your gist - https://gist.github.com/pengwynn/6366324#file-2-sh - it DOES NOT includes LINK in Response Headers (and as you see in gist above, you actually have 575 pages (with 1 repo in each page)! That's exactly a problem :) We don't know if we should process next page or we should stop if we use Conditional Requests.

Comment: I seems found an answer (trivial) and update question with it. What you think?